# Facebook debug tool fails on 302s checking cookie support

Tags: facebook, http-status-code-302

I got a website where I use 302s to redirect to a specific, non-existent URI which checks (the lack of) support of cookies by the browser.

Calling the `/` URI thus ends up in a 'cycle' `/ -> /cookiescheck/ -> /`.

However, I see this error:

```
Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.
  original http://www.example.com/
  302      http://www.example.com/cookiescheck/
```

However it says underneath that HTTP redirects would be followed.

What is wrong there?

Comment: You probably need to inspect the headers and make sure to whitelist the facebook crawler's user agent and not redirect to cookiecheck

Comment: Considering that one time or another it works and the rest of it it does not, I suspect a problem with multiple redirects support from the Facebook crawler.

Comment: Not sure about that. In all cases, you should be special casing bots.